# Can I Message Spring Integration Channel from within My Inbound Channel Adapter Handler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm looking to message another channel, if certain conditions merit, from within the handler of my file inbound-channel-adapter. Sometimes the inbound file has out of specification values and I'd like to send the file to an error directory, but not interrupt the flow of the inbound to outbound since even the out of specification file still needs to goto a secondary location.

Example of my configuration:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn"
                                  directory="${input.path}"
                                  filename-regex="\\d{8}-\\d+\\.txt">
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-rate="500"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-file:file-to-string-transformer input-channel="filesIn"
                                     output-channel="strings"
                                     delete-files="true" />

<int:channel id="strings"/>
<int:channel id="errorChannel" />

<int:exception-type-router input-channel="strings"
                           default-output-channel="output">
    <int:mapping exception-type="ca.uhn.hl7v2.HL7Exception"
                 channel="errorChannel"/>
</int:exception-type-router>

<int:service-activator input-channel="output"
                               output-channel="archive"
                               ref="handler" method="handleString"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel"
                       output-channel="errorOutput"
                       ref="handler" method="handleError" />

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="archive"
                                   directory="${archive.path}"
                                   delete-source-files="true"/>

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="errorOutput"
                                   directory="${hl7.error.path}"/>

<bean id="handler" class="com.giotta.service.Hl7MessageConsumer"/>
```

[image: Crude Diagram]

Answer (score 1):

From a terminology perspective, inbound adapters don't have "handlers". Depending on the type, they are either message sources or message producers.

That said, you can add a router immediately after the inbound adapter and route to different channels based on whatever criteria you want.

**EDIT**

> The exception is thrown within the Hl7MessageConsumer while trying to parse the String into a HL7 message

But you currently have

...>transformer->etr->handler->...

i.e. the etr is **before** the handler.

You need something like...

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn"
                                  directory="${input.path}"
                                  filename-regex="\\d{8}-\\d+\\.txt">
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-rate="500" error-channel="errorChannel" />
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-file:file-to-string-transformer input-channel="filesIn"
                                     output-channel="strings"
                                     delete-files="true" />

<int:channel id="strings"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="strings"
                               output-channel="archive"
                               ref="handler" method="handleString"/>

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="archive"
                                   directory="${archive.path}"
                                   delete-source-files="true"/>

<int:channel id="errorChannel" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel"
                       output-channel="errorOutput"
                       ref="handler" method="handleError" />

<int-file:outbound-channel-adapter id="errorOutput"
                                   directory="${hl7.error.path}"/>

<bean id="handler" class="com.giotta.service.Hl7MessageConsumer"/>
```

i.e. the poller catches the exception and routes an `ErrorMessage` to the error channel. The error message payload is a `MessagingException` with two properties (`cause` and `failedMessage`).

**EDIT2**

> I still want the string to goto the "archive" adapter in addition to the "errorOutput" adapter.

In that case...

```
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="errorChannel" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel"
                       output-channel="errorOutput"
                       ref="handler" method="handleError" />

<int:transformer input-channel="errorChannel"
            output-channel="archive" expression="payload.failedMessage" />
```

Comment: I've played with the exception-type-router, but I still want the original inbound file to continue to the outbound as well as the error channel if an error has occurred. I can't seem to figure out how to get it go to both. Also one or the other. Any tips?

Comment: I mean you can use a custom router to examine the file and route to one channel or another, based on your acceptance criteria. It's not clear what you mean by using an exception type router, there is no exception yet. Perhaps if you edit your question to show some configuration that you have tried, it might help us understand more what you mean.

Comment: I've added my configuration.

Comment: The exception type router makes no sense there - the payload is a String, not an exception. You need to use a custom router if you want to use some special criteria to decided whether the String should go to errors or output. Who throws an `HL7Exception` ??

Comment: The exception is thrown within the Hl7MessageConsumer while trying to parse the String into a HL7 message.

Comment: But you have the etr in the main flow before the handler - it needs to be on an error channel flow. See my edit.

Comment: This was exactly like my first attempt. It works, but not the way I was looking for. I still want the string to goto the "archive" adapter in addition to the "errorOutput" adapter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103864/discussion-between-john-giotta-and-gary-russell).

Comment: Correct to the second edit - you need a transformer not a bridge.